# extracting data java jsoup html

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

i want to extract the text "Banking and credit" from the link http://ica-ap.coop/AboutUs/association-asian-confederation-credit-unions-accu

i tried with this code :

```
    Document doc = Utils.getFromURL("http://ica-ap.coop/AboutUs/association-asian-confederation-credit-unions-accu");

    Elements e = doc.select("div.field-items div.field-item.even table[width=523]");    

    Element ab = e.select("thead tr td p").first();

    System.out.println(ab.text());
```

but it dosnt work.

Do have an idea?

Comment: The text is not in the `thead`, but in the `tbody` ...

Comment: "but it dosnt work." is not enough to properly describe problem. Please [edit] your question and include specific problem description like error message/exception stacktrace/expected vs. actual result.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://ica-ap.coop/AboutUs/association-asian-confederation-credit-unions-accu").get();
    Elements e = doc.select("div.field-items div.field-item.even table[width=523]");    

    Element ab = e.select("tbody tr:nth-child(1) p").last(); //content is tbody not thead

    System.out.println(ab.text());
```